# Qt Build Error

Tags: qt, embedded, makefile, arm

After configuring with

```
$./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -opensource
```

I get this output when Making and can't figure out why:

../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arm.h: In function `char q_atomic_swp(volatile 
   char*, char)':
../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arm.h:125: warning: address requested for`ret', 
   which is declared `register'
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp: In function`void qt_core_init_boilerplate()':
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:581: `__builtin_exit' undeclared (first use this 
   function)
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:581: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once 
   for each function it appears in.)
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:573: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:573: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:574: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:574: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:575: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:576: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:576: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:577: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:578: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:578: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:579: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:580: warning: statement with no effect
global/qlibraryinfo.cpp:580: warning: statement with no effect
make[1]: *** [.obj/release-shared-emb-arm/qlibraryinfo.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/bsalmi/Desktop/qt-embedded-linux-opensource-src-4.5.1/src/corelib'
make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem or what to look into?

Thank You
Bryce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post out from the QT mailing lists:

http://lists.trolltech.com/pipermail/qt-embedded-interest/2009-March/000224.html